# KeyReleased Java Method Doesn't Work

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to make two objects which are able to move on all 4 directions ( **UP**, **DOWN**, **RIGHT**,**LEFT**). First Object should be controlled with the **W**,**S**,**D**,**A** - while the second one should be controlled on **UP**,**DOWN**,**RIGHT**,**LEFT** arrows and it works.

However, I want them to stop after I release buttons (which means they can only move if user is holding some of those buttons), but I can't get what I want. Since my KeyPressed() method works, I'll only put the code of KeyReleased.

I used CTRL+SHIF+F, so it's not in the best order now, but I'll hope it's readable. As I mentioned in the topic, I'm using Java.

```
 public void keyRealsed(KeyEvent e)
{
  int key = e.getKeyCode();

  for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) 

  {

     GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

     if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player)
     {

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
           tempObject.setVelY(0); 
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
           tempObject.setVelY(0);
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
           tempObject.setVelX(0);
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
           tempObject.setVelX(0);
     }

     if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player2)
     {

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
           tempObject.setVelY(0); 
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
           tempObject.setVelY(0);
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
           tempObject.setVelX(0);
        else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
           tempObject.setVelX(0);
     }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: You spelled released wrong.

Comment: nice eye, shit happens :(

Comment: haha no worries, just if you are in a keylistener and using that method if it isn't spelled correctly it wont work :)

Comment: Roger that, thank you !

Comment: @Seinfeld, that is why you should always use `@Override` every time you override a method. The compiler will then spot typos for you.

Answer (score 0):

As Jordan Seanor said above, change the name to `keyReleased` you simply misspelled it. This should work.